# Highcharts live graph: Accessing Datetime data returns an [Object] instead of [Datetime, Int]

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, live

I created a minimal reproduction of this problem, so as to make it easy for someone to help me figure this out.

This is what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/tDW7e/1/

```
    $(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var chart;
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            //animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        document.getElementById('dbg').innerHTML = series.toString();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            })()
        }]
    });
});
});
```

HTML:

```
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <div id="dbg" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I edited the Live Chart demo, to write the value of the data to a second div. I am trying to perform a check to make sure that the most recent DateTime value in the graph is not the most  recent in my database. I cannot perform this check because what should be an array of [DateTime, Int] becomes an array of [Object].

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your example you are using `series` which always is array of objects.

Second thing, each of points is also object, otherwise you couldn't use for example `point.update()` to update new options etc.

Third thing, in your example you are creating points as:

```
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
```

Which obviously is an object, not an array.

If you want to get actual point, use: `series.options.data`, and if using proper format (as you said) use this: http://jsfiddle.net/tDW7e/4/

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for. Now that you have pointed these few thing out, it is so obvious, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tDW7e/3/) will be helpful.

```
setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        var lastIndex = series.data.length - 1;
                        document.getElementById('dbg').innerHTML = 'x : ' + series.data[lastIndex].x + ' y: ' + series.data[lastIndex].y;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, this demonstrated what I was looking for, when I tried it this way there must have been something else wrong in my code that it said was "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Your series object contains points which are objects containing x and y values. Of you want to print it out, consider using JSON.stringify e.g.

```
document.getElementById('dbg').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(series.data);
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be useful for me in the future!